# Zoom image given x and y

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have an image which as a "ruler" (made of basic divs positioned absolute on top of the image) that are use to measure the ends of the image. Now the idea is that if you long press one of the ruler ends (the dots at the end of the line which are draggable), the image in the background would zoom in that point, and follow the dot if the user moves it. I am able to detect the long press but I cannot get the image to zoom and follow the dot once detected. The code below is where I have done the detection and now I should apply the styling to move the image. I thought of using the transition property but couldn't get it to zoom on the dot. Any help is appreciated...

Here's a codesandbox with how the ruler works: [Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-wind-7l0oh?file=/src/App.js)

**Meaningful code**:

```js
const x = get('x', varToUse); //This just gives the x coordinate of the ruler end
const y = get('y', varToUse); //This just gives the y coordinate of the ruler end

const image = ruler.current.parentElement.parentElement.childNodes[1].childNodes[1];

if (zoom) {
  image.style.transform = `translate(${x * 2}px, ${y * 2}px) scale(2.0)`;
} else {
  image.style.transform = `scale(1.0)`;
}
```

This is what the ruler looks like just to get an understanding:
[image]

Comment: I'm not really following. Can you try to clarify your question text a bit, or provide more visual examples?

Comment: I update the question hopefully is a bit clearer

Comment: could you please add more code? I want to see how you handled mouse events.

Comment: Sure I am using react spring and react-use-gesture hope is not a problem

Comment: Added a sandbox to see it working

Comment: Are you looking for the transform-origin property? Because changing that according to the (relative) position of the dot would do the trick IMO...

Comment: Thank you it seems it does. But now when I remove the zoom the dot does not respect the placement of the zoomed version any tips?

Answer (score 0):

You can make the image a div with background-image.

```
.image {
    background-image: url({image_url});
}
```

so this way you can update the image size and position easily with this properties

```
.image {
    background-size: x y;
    background-position x y;
}
```

I think this way is easier to do the image resizing and zoom abilities.

another way is to use a canvas library that can help you a lot they have lots of built in functions.

I think trying it without library is better for now but as it grows try to move to a canvas library

Answer (score 0):

The first reason is that in the code you provided, the DOM element that is being manipulated is a div id='root'. The image should be selected.